# "switch out the lights" vs "switch off the lights

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions, idiomatic-language, phrasal-verbs

In CNN, it used "**switch out the lights.**"

According to what I know, it should be **"switch off the lights."**

I checked the subtitles to confirm I understood it correctly, and I'm right. It says "**switch out the lights**".

Is it correct to use it?

Comment: In informal speech, "switch out the lights" is acceptable. In something prepared, it would be a mistake. Literally, "switch out the lights" means "replace the lights".

Comment: And it might be a term taken from stage production, i.e., argot.

Comment: It may be a mistake.

Comment: In UK English we can brighten a place by _putting on_ or _switching on_ lights and make it dark by _putting them out_, _putting them off_, or _switching them off_. In everyday speech, 'switch out the light' might be understood as meaning 'turn it off'. However, engineers or technicians operating systems such as power grids, railway signalling systems, etc, can use 'switch out' to mean 'disconnect', (a part of the system) so I wonder if @DrMoishePippik may be on to something.

Comment: In BrE we _change out_ a part of something, e.g. a component, module, or assembly when we replace it. 'Switch out' is rather American.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, both terms seem to be seen with equal frequency in the USA, in my experience, though I haven't done a web search on usage. Now, if you said "bonnet" or "boot", few in the US would know where to look on a vehicle, and a "trolley" is a (very) light rail vehicle, not a shopping cart there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Switch out the lights" is just an alternative way of saying "switch off the lights".  You will also hear things like "turn out the lights", and "put out the lights".  These are common variations.  There's no difference in meaning.

They all mean to flip a switch in order to turn off the light.

I think it highly unlikely in the context of your example, but in some case "switch out" can also mean to exchange one thing for another, and there may be some technically distinct terminology when it comes to electrical engineering (but I'm not qualified to answer that).

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between 'switch out the lights' and 'switch off the lights'

switch out= to remove something from an electrical circuit to turn it off. (It also means 'disconnect'.)

Switch out the lights. or Switch the lights  out.

switch off=(turn off)= to stop a device powered by electricity

Switch off the lights. or Switch the lights off.